# How do I perform Firestore admin tasks from a server-side Dart application?

Tags: firebase, dart, sdk, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on putting together a server-side Dart application that will run in App Engine. It needs to access a Firestore database, but I'm having trouble doing so.

The Dart packages I've tried are:

- [`firebase_admin_interop`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admin_interop)
- [`firebase`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase)

In both cases, I get errors like this when attempting to execute my code:

```
file:///root/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_admin_interop-1.2.2/lib/src/database.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
```

My vague understanding of this error is that it means the library has a dependency on running in a browser. However, I've not been able to find any way to interact with Firestore in a server-to-server configuration using Dart.

Is my only recourse here to use the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Firebase Admin SDK for Dart. So indeed the REST API would be your best best.

Note that much of the Admin functionality is not exposed in documented REST API. So ymmv, and I'd seriously consider switching to a platform where you can use one of the official Admin SDKs.

Comment: What about this one (which I just found): https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/googleapis. Sounds promising?

Comment: The Firebase APIs don't fall under `googleapis`. But you can use the auth from that package and call the Firebase REST APIs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/index

Comment: They do though. They're listed in the readme for that package and I just managed to retrieve a document from my DB using it.

Comment: Given that you're a Firebase engineer at Google (!) I suspect I'm missing something, but I have indeed used the `googleapis` and `googleapis_auth` packages to retrieve data from Firestore when running inside a Dart application. What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that you're trying to access Firestore in the comment thread. Some of Firebase's newer APIs (the ones listed on that page) *are* indeed callable as `googleapi`s. From your experience it seems that the Dart package you found provides a friendly wrapper around the native REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of search results on google are an indicator for popularity, then
**Go, Node.js and C# are the languages most people use with the firestore admin libraries**

Google searched input taken from https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers

Go: "`cloud.google.com/go/firestore`" -> 3890 results
Node.js: "`require('@google-cloud/firestore')`" -> 2120 results
C#: "`FirestoreDb.Create`" -> 1110
Python: "`from google.cloud import firestore`" -> 859 results
Java: "`import com.google.cloud.firestore.Firestore`" -> 601 results
PHP: "`Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient`" -> 1 result